# Exporting a trained TensorFlow models to C++ in windows

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I want to use a trained TensorFlow model for validation\test in a visual studio C++ project, windows 7 environment.

Theoretically, I guess there are two options that seems reasonable for me:

indirect option: build an EXE or DLL file warping the python trained model (graph and weights) and run this files within the C++ visual studio project
direct option: inlcude directly TensorFlow libs in the VS and import the trained model
I can't find any documentation or examples how to do so in windows. Any suggestions what is the best way to do it?

The configuration i have is: Windows 7\10 TensorFlow 1.0.1 Python 3.5.2 Visual Studio 2015